# O-Group names of Salmonella serotypes?

Tags: molecular-biology, antigen

What liposaccharides are represented by the O-group designations of Salmonalla serovars in the Kauffman-White classification scheme?  I mean to ask, how do the numbers in a Sal serovar (1, 9, & 12 for Enteriditis, for example) describe the oligosaccharide(s) present on the cell membrane?  Continuing said example, does 1, 9, 12  indicate three different types of liposaccharides, or one type of oligosaccahride containing three distinct features?